# LWC in Visualforce Getting Field Values

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am working with an org that is currently in classic. I have a requirement to take a few different buttons on a record page and combine their functionality into one app that will launch a VF page from a button. I have played around with using Lightning Out. I am hoping it will be more performant and let me work with modern JS. I am hoping that someone can help me with a couple of questions

1. At times the page seems to load very slowly. I am wondering if there is a flaw in my implementation. This seems to happen most often when I have just opened Salesforce.
2. And is there a way to pass other values in from the record when the page is launched. I would like to pass in the email value from the record, I am currently taking the record Id and using wired Apex to get the field values.

The VF page

```
<apex:page id="PasswordOktaButtons" standardController="Patient__c" showHeader="false" sideBar="false" >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lwcContainer"></div>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:Okta", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:passwordButtons", {"recordId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}"}, "lwcContainer",
            function (component) {}
            );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

The Aura App

```
aura:application description="Okta" extends="ltng:outApp" access="global">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:passwordButtons"/>
</aura:application>
```

LWC Markup - Note the nested component only consists of HTML with a single

tag.

```
<template>
    <template if:true={recordId}>
        <template if:true={patient}>
            <p>Wired patient called</p>
        </template>
        <lightning-card title="Okta Buttons Component" >
            <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Reset Password" onclick={handleReset}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Unfreeze User" onclick={handleUnfreeze}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button variant="Neutral" label="Login History" onclick={handleLoginHistory}></lightning-button>
            <div>
                <c-okta-login-history ></c-okta-login-history>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>

    </template>
</template>
```

LWC JS

```
import {LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getPatient from '@salesforce/apex/PatientController.getPatient';


export default class PasswordButtons extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    @track patient
    @track email

    @wire(getPatient, {id : '$recordId'})wiredPatient({error, data}){
            this.patient = data;
            console.log(error);
            console.log('value of patient = ' + JSON.stringify(this.patient));
            if (data){
                this.email = this.patient['Email__c'];
               }
            }

    handleReset(){
        console.log('clicked password reset and record id = ' + this.recordId);
        confirm('have you confirmed this patient? ');
    }
    handleUnfreeze(){
        console.log('clicked unfreeze user and record id = ' + this.recordId);
    }
    handleLoginHistory(){
        console.log('clicked login history and record id = ' + this.recordId);
    }

}
```

Simple controller method

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Patient__c getPatient(String id){        
        Patient__c p = [SELECT Email__c
        FROM Patient__c WHERE Id =: id
        LIMIT 1];       
        return p;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Visualforce page will basically load after all other components on the app. Only after it will load the LWC will start to render. So performance wise it still not ideal.
2. In order to pass different parameters from the Visualforce into the LWC component you can fetch them using a custom controller or custom [extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm).  Than just like you pass the recordId you can add extra param.

   `<script>
     $Lightning.use("c:Okta", function () {
     $Lightning.createComponent("c:passwordButtons", {
       "recordId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}",
       "ContactEmail":"{!Contact.Email}"}, 
       "lwcContainer",
       function (component) {}
       );
    });
   </script>`

Comment: Great and thanks for the help. Do you think using Lightning Out is a good choice or should the development just be done in VF then?

Comment: As far as I know LWC is the way forward and reduce much of the complexity as well as round trips to server from a performance perspective. So you kinda paying a price on initial load but once it’s loaded it’s much faster and will support many more future use cases.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too